# MongoDB: ¿Equivalente a función date() de MySQL?

Tags: mongodb

Estoy haciendo una consulta con el *agreggation framework* de MongoDB y quería saber si existe una función equivalente a `date()` de MySQL, que dada una fecha dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss te devuelva solamente dd/mm/aaaa.

Huelga decir que `$date` no existe y `$toDate` parece agregar siempre hh:mm:ss al resultado aunque sea en forma 00:00:00.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

**EDICIÓN**:

Parto de un array generado con un `$lookup` que luego descompongo con un `$unwind`; en la BD la información se encuentra así:

```
{
  ...
  "data": {
    "inicio": "2023-06-22T09:15:57+06:30",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Yo hago, dentro de un `$project`:

```
"dtBroadcastDay": {"$toDate": "$array.data.inicio"},
```

Y obtengo la fecha así:

```
"dtBroadcastDay":ISODate("2021-01-19T23:55:45.000+01:00")
```

Quiero sólo dd/mm/aaaa, como hace MySQL con `date()`.

Comment: Hola, una duda. ¿Has probado usar algo como esto  ``var fecha = new Date();`` ? Esto en la terminal de mongo.

Comment: Por favor añade el código de lo que estás tratando hacer y muestra cuál es el resultado deseado y cuál es el obtenido actualmente. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener la fecha en formato `dd-mm-yyyy` en un campo de un documento de MongoDB. El mismo se debe extraer de un campo que contiene un tipo `String` con el siguiente formato: `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss+HH:mm` (formato [ISO-8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es usar el operador [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) de MongoDB para el proceso de agregación, que recibe 1 parámetro obligatorio (`date`) y 3 opcionales:

```js
{ $dateToString: {
    date: <dateExpression>,
    format: <formatString>,
    timezone: <tzExpression>,
    onNull: <expression>
} }
```

Siendo el `<dateExpression>` una expresión (valor) de fecha válida que resuelva a un tipo [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date), [`Timestamp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-timestamp) u [`ObejctId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-object-id) de MongoDB.

Por ejemplo:

```js
"$project": {
  //...
  "dtBroadcastDay": {
    "$dateToString": { // <- convierte un tipo Date en un String
      "date": {
        "$toDate": "$array.data.inicio" // <- devuelve un objeto Date
      },
      "format": "%d-%m-%Y" // <- formato dd-mm-yyyy
    }
  },
//...
```

Puedes consultar los especificadores de formato en [la documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#format-specifiers).

Si no especificas una zona horaria, se asume UTC.

El siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aJaLoaGzhV7) muestra un ejemplo del uso de dicho operador.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.